# awk lookup values from a file with a different RS

Tags: awk, sed

I found a lot of examples of using awk to lookup values from one file in other one, but all of them have the same FS and RS. I wonder if there is a way to achieve the same for files where FS and RS are different. I know that it can be achieved with pre-transformation of one of the files, but I was wondering if there is any elegant solution for that.

So as in below, search for keys from file1, which are not found in the second in `dn:` records.

file1:

```
key1,field1_1,field2_1
key2,field1_2,field2_2
key3,field1_3,field2_3
```

file2:

```
dn: key1,xxxxxx
sn: field1_1
l: field2_1

dn: key2,xxxxxx
sn: field1_2
l: field2_2
```

So, the desired output should be `key3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{keys[$2]; next} !($1 in keys){print $1}' RS='' FS='[[:space:],:]+' file2 RS='\n' FS=',' file1
key3
```

Comment: Oh, beautiful! I didn't know it can be specified for every file in the list :) Also +1 for the idea to split one line into further fields in `file2`